# How do you pass variables between functions when importing scripts, sense self.function does not work when code is imported

Tags: python, class

I have a larger script, called scriptA, and a smaller script called scriptB. I import and source scriptB into scriptA. ScriptB contains variables I want to utilize in scriptA, but I do not know how to pass those variables from scriptB to scriptA.  Normally, if I make a class in a script, i can use the self.variable syntax, and all the methods within that class will see and be able to use that new variable. But a variable in scriptB is not seen by scriptA when I import and source scriptB. How can I solve this problem, thank you.

scriptA:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/alfredwinters/Desktop/python/scripts/")
import scriptB
reload(scriptB)
import maya.cmds as cmds

def scriptA_function():
    variable = scriptB.scriptB_function.variable
    print variable

scriptA_function()
```

scriptB:

```
def scriptB_function():
    variable = "apple"
```

right now I get the error:
*# Error: AttributeError: file  line 8: 'function' object has no attribute 'variable' #*

Comment: You have to call that variable by `scriptB.classname.variablename`,

Comment: You can do `from scriptB import variable1` and use that `variable1` anywhere in `scriptA`

Comment: If scriptB has no class, would the correct syntax be: variable = scriptB.function.variablename

Comment: It would be much better if you posted a minimal example showing your issue instead of attempting to discuss in the abstract.

Comment: updated with code example

Comment: I don't think you can import from inside a function. You will have to return it from the function and expose it outside. Else you have to define variable in global scope and modify it inside the function and also, call the function once.

Comment: `scriptB_function.variable` is not visible even to the rest of `scriptB`. The quick and dirty fix is to make it `global` but all the usual warning bells should go off. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish and is it really necessary to break encapsulation to get there?